# HTML/CSS: horizontally center text after reflow

Tags: html, css

I'm sure this has been answered before, but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

I have a toolbar with links:

[image]

Once I resize the browser, text reflows:

[image]

The question is how do I center that text after the reflow? `text-align` doesn't help here, neither does `margin: 0 auto`.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="desktop">
  <div>
    <a class="root-nav-links" href="/details">Event Details</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="root-nav-links" href="/details">...</a>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.desktop {
  display:                            flex;
  align-items:                        center;
}
.root-nav-links {
  margin:                             0 15px;
  padding:                            2px 6px;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a snippet here with the issue to play around with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: block` & `text-align: center` property on `.root-nav-links`, like:

```
.root-nav-links {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin:0 15px;
  padding:2px 6px;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below (*try compressing the browser width*):

```css
.desktop {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #6440C0;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.root-nav-links {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 15px;
  padding: 2px 6px;
  color: white;
}

.root-nav-links:hover {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="desktop">
  <div>
    <a class="root-nav-links" href="/eventdetails">Event Details</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="root-nav-links" href="/schedule">Schedule</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="root-nav-links" href="/floorplan">Floor Plan</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="root-nav-links" href="/details">Directory</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm kind of curious why so many of the other answers were downvoted when they had a similar suggestion to this one.

Answer (score 0):

`div` -> `text-align: center`

links -> `block`

```css
.desktop {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.desktop div {
  text-align: center;
}

.root-nav-links {
  display: block;
  margin:  0 15px;
  padding: 2px 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="desktop">
  <div>
    <a class="root-nav-links" href="/details">Event Details</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="root-nav-links" href="/details">...</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.desktop {
  display:                            flex;
  align-items:                        center;
}
.root-nav-links {
  margin:                             0 15px;
  padding:                            2px 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="desktop">
  <div>
    <a class="root-nav-links" href="/details">Event Details</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="root-nav-links" href="/details">Long Long Word</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

It looks like treating each element as an inline block and adding align-center to them should center the text when the words are forced onto multiple lines. Based on the comments I'm now less certain this is what you were asking about.

Answer (score -1):

It should be like this:
Html

```
<div class="desktop">
  <div class="extra-div">
     <a class="root-nav-links" href="/details">Event Details</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.extra-div {
   display:flex;
   align-items: center;
 }
.root-nav-links {
  margin: 0 15px;
  padding: 2px 6px;
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/622L0mqz/